# Azure servicebus ReceiveBatch only returns 2 messages

Tags: azure, batch-processing, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to periodically receive all messages in a servicebus queue. But when I call ReceiveBatch(1000) I max get 2 messages back.

This question is kind of related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187172/service-bus-session-receivebatchasync-only-receiving-1-message), except he would get a lot more by calling ReceiveBatch multiple times, I do not.

**How do I get all messages on a servicebus queue?**

Answer (score 0):

The name `ReceiveBatch(maximumNumber)` is somewhat misleading. You don't get a batch, you get a collection of up-to maximum number of messages. This means you can receive less than `maximuNumber` as well. If you wish to receive a specific amount, you'd need to loop through the receiving operation until you get that number of messages (and potentially slightly more).

Comment: I have tried looping, but only getting 2 messages per loop makes it seem like I'm missing some setting somewhere